# How do I change "Version Release Control" after submitting an app to the Apple app store

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I just submitted a new version of our app to the Apple app store, but I had previously turned on "Version Release Control" so the app will now wait for me to initiate distribution to the iTunes App Store after it has (hopefully) been approved.

I would like to change this so that it just gets automatically sent to the App store after approval. How can I do that?

Julian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you can't. You must wait for the app to be accepted or reject your build and change it (starting all over in the wait list...)